# Open WinSCP Command window/Open Terminal(Ctrl + T) window directly in Windows environment

Tags: winscp, winscp-net

Is there a way Ii can open WinSCP Command window/Open Terminal (Ctrl + T) window directly and pass `du` command to it through code/scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To automate this operation, use the [`call` scripting command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call):

```
call du
```

A complete Windows batch file would be like:

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "call du" ^
    "exit"
```

---

Though note that WinSCP is a file transfer application. While WinSCP can execute shell commands, using a terminal application to execute commands is more natural.

For example with [PuTTY Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html), you can do:

```
plink.exe -ssh username@example.com du
```